# How to loop through website with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to loop through [this site](https://www.booklooker.de/buecher-schnaeppchen) and click on each book-element in the `list`. That means for this example first on:

1. [Leo Lausemaus will nicht teilen Pixi ...](https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Marco-Campanella-Illustrationen-Anna-Casalis-Originaltext+Leo-Lausemaus-will-nicht-teilen-Pixi-Buch/id/A02A6DCY01ZZQ)
2. [Löcher - Die Geheimnisse von Green Lake](https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Louis-Sachar+L%C3%B6cher-Die-Geheimnisse-von-Green-Lake/id/A02Acf2901ZZJ)
3. ...

In the marked part of the HTML file is an `<a>` thats `href` takes you to the page I want to go to first:
[image]

With BeautifulSoup I am able to extract that part of the code, where the `<a>` is.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get(https://www.booklooker.de/buecher-schnaeppchen)
souped = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
test = souped.find_all(class_="resultList_desc")  
for i in test:
    result = i.find('a')
```

Here is the result from the code:

```
<a href="/B%C3%BCcher/Marco-Campanella-Illustrationen-Anna-Casalis-Originaltext+Leo-Lausemaus-will-nicht-teilen-Pixi-Buch/id/A02A6DCY01ZZQ"><span class="artikeltitel notranslate" id="ID2365796060">Leo Lausemaus will nicht teilen Pixi Buch Nr. 1987 Einzeltitel aus Pixi Serie 219 Leo Lausemaus</span></a>
<a href="/B%C3%BCcher/Louis-Sachar+L%C3%B6cher-Die-Geheimnisse-von-Green-Lake/id/A02Acf2901ZZJ"><span class="artikeltitel notranslate" id="ID2367131489">Löcher - Die Geheimnisse von Green Lake</span></a>
<a href="/B%C3%BCcher/Iny-Lorentz+Die-Wanderhure/id/A02Aaimc01ZZj"><span class="artikeltitel notranslate" id="ID2366667608">Die Wanderhure</span></a>
...
```

After that I want to click on each element in the `list` to get to the respective page that is stored in the href attribute.

This part is my problem. I don't know how to get to the wepages from this `list`.

Comment: You tagged the question with `selenium` what is missleading, while example uses `requests`. There seems to be a mix in your wording, with `selenium` you could use a click action with `requests` you send an additional request. Also  `<a>` is the tag and `href` an attribute of this tag.  Hope this helps to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are close to your goal, simply iterate your list and `.get('href')` from your `<a>`s to request the detail pages - I worked with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for convenience here to select each item and used the value of `href` attribute concatinated with the base url:

```
for e in soup.select('[id^="article_"]'):
    soup_p = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.booklooker.de/'+e.a.get('href')).text)
```

The scraped contents ar stored as `dict` in a `list`

```
    data.append({
        'title':soup_p.h1.text
    })
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.booklooker.de/buecher-schnaeppchen')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)

data = []
for e in soup.select('[id^="article_"]'):
    soup_p = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.booklooker.de/'+e.a.get('href')).content)
    
    d = {
        'title':soup_p.h1.text,
        'whatever': 'should be scraped'
    }
    d.update(dict([x.strip() for x in row.text.split(':', 1)] for row in soup_p.select('table.articleDetails tr:not(:has(td[colspan]))')))
    data.append(d)
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'Leo Lausemaus will nicht teilen Pixi Buch Nr. 1987 Einzeltitel aus Pixi Serie 219 Leo Lausemaus – Buch gebraucht kaufen', 'whatever': 'should be scraped', 'Autor/in': 'Anna Casalis (Originaltext), Marco Campanella (Illustrationen)', 'Titel': 'Leo Lausemaus will nicht teilen Pixi Buch Nr. 1987 Einzeltitel aus Pixi Serie 219 Leo Lausemaus', 'ISBN': '9783551050519 (ISBN-10: 3551050511)', 'Zustand': 'wie neu', 'Verlag': 'Carlsen Verlag GmbH', 'Format': '10 x 10 cm', 'Seiten': '24', 'Gewicht': '20\xa0g', 'Ort': 'Hamburg', 'Auflage': '2. Auflage 2014', 'Erschienen': 'c2013', 'Einband': 'Taschenbuch', 'Sprache': 'Deutsch', 'Beschreibung': 'Leo Lausemaus will nicht teilen Pixi Buch Nr. 1987 Einzeltitel aus Pixi Serie 219 Leo Lausemaus, Carlsen Verlag GmbH c2013, 2. Auflage 2014, Minibuch, Originalfoto, sehr gut erhalten und fast wie neu mit minimalen Gebrauchsspuren, minimal angestoßen, keine Einträge, schneller Versand nach Zahlungseingang!', 'Verlagstext': 'Neun Jahre währt nun der Siegeszug von Leo Lausemaus in deutschen Kinderzimmern. Über eine Million Mal haben sich die Geschichten in dieser Zeit verkauft. Das Erfolgsgeheimnis: Leo Lausemaus greift die großen Themen des Kindergartenaltes auf und setzt sich dabei behutsam und liebevoll mit den typischen Konfliktsituationen auseinander.', 'Stichwörter': 'Ab 3 Jahren, Bilderbücher, Billige Bücher, Erste Bücher, Geschenke Kinder, Kinderbuch, Kindergeschichten, Minibuch, Pixie, Vorlesebuch', 'Bestell-Nr.': 'BN14133', 'Sparte': 'Bücher: Kinderbücher / Jugendbücher: Pixi-Bücher>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer in dieser Sparte>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer von diesem Autor>> Alle Sparten dieses Verkäufers'}, {'title': 'Löcher - Die Geheimnisse von Green Lake – Buch gebraucht kaufen', 'whatever': 'should be scraped', 'Autor/in': 'Louis Sachar', 'Titel': 'Löcher - Die Geheimnisse von Green Lake', 'ISBN': '9783407740984 (ISBN-10: 3407740980)', 'Zustand': 'wie neu', 'Verlag': 'Julius Beltz GmbH & Co. KG', 'Format': '187x125x17 mm', 'Seiten': '296', 'Gewicht': '295\xa0g', 'Einband': 'Taschenbuch', 'Sprache': 'Deutsch', 'Beschreibung': 'Tierfreier Nichtraucher-Haushalt Versand als Bücher-/Warensendung', 'Verlagstext': 'Schon der Anfang ist unglaublich: Stanley Yelnats geht nichts ahnend unter einer Brücke durch, als ihm die riesigen, übel riechenden Turnschuhe eines berühmten Baseballspielers auf den Kopf fallen. Und weil sein Vater an einem bahnbrechenden Recycling-Verfahren mit gebrauchten Turnschuhen arbeitet, hält Stanley die müffelnden Treter für ein Zeichen und nimmt sie mit. Pech, dass die Polizei schon nach dem Dieb sucht. Der Jugendrichter lässt Stanley die Wahl: Jugendgefängnis oder 18 Monate Camp Green Lake. Er entscheidet sich für das Camp. Die Hitze dort ist unerträglich, der Alltag hart, doch so schnell gibt Stanley nicht auf.', 'Angebot vom': '25.08.2022', 'Bestell-Nr.': 'BN0098', 'Sparte': 'Bücher: Kinderbücher / Jugendbücher: Jugendbuch allgemein>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer in dieser Sparte>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer von diesem Autor>> Alle Sparten dieses Verkäufers'},...]
```

`data` converted to `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  | title | whatever | Autor/in | Titel | ISBN | Zustand | Verlag | Format | Seiten | Gewicht | Ort | Auflage | Erschienen | Einband | Sprache | Beschreibung | Verlagstext | Stichwörter | Bestell-Nr. | Sparte | Angebot vom | Lieferzeit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Leo Lausemaus will nicht teilen Pixi Buch Nr. 1987 Einzeltitel aus Pixi Serie 219 Leo Lausemaus – Buch gebraucht kaufen | should be scraped | Anna Casalis (Originaltext), Marco Campanella (Illustrationen) | Leo Lausemaus will nicht teilen Pixi Buch Nr. 1987 Einzeltitel aus Pixi Serie 219 Leo Lausemaus | 9783551050519 (ISBN-10: 3551050511) | wie neu | Carlsen Verlag GmbH | 10 x 10 cm | 24 | 20 g | Hamburg | 2. Auflage 2014 | c2013 | Taschenbuch | Deutsch | Leo Lausemaus will nicht teilen Pixi Buch Nr. 1987 Einzeltitel aus Pixi Serie 219 Leo Lausemaus, Carlsen Verlag GmbH c2013, 2. Auflage 2014, Minibuch, Originalfoto, sehr gut erhalten und fast wie neu mit minimalen Gebrauchsspuren, minimal angestoßen, keine Einträge, schneller Versand nach Zahlungseingang! | Neun Jahre währt nun der Siegeszug von Leo Lausemaus in deutschen Kinderzimmern. Über eine Million Mal haben sich die Geschichten in dieser Zeit verkauft. Das Erfolgsgeheimnis: Leo Lausemaus greift die großen Themen des Kindergartenaltes auf und setzt sich dabei behutsam und liebevoll mit den typischen Konfliktsituationen auseinander. | Ab 3 Jahren, Bilderbücher, Billige Bücher, Erste Bücher, Geschenke Kinder, Kinderbuch, Kindergeschichten, Minibuch, Pixie, Vorlesebuch | BN14133 | Bücher: Kinderbücher / Jugendbücher: Pixi-Bücher>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer in dieser Sparte>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer von diesem Autor>> Alle Sparten dieses Verkäufers | nan | nan |
| 1 | Löcher - Die Geheimnisse von Green Lake – Buch gebraucht kaufen | should be scraped | Louis Sachar | Löcher - Die Geheimnisse von Green Lake | 9783407740984 (ISBN-10: 3407740980) | wie neu | Julius Beltz GmbH & Co. KG | 187x125x17 mm | 296 | 295 g | nan | nan | nan | Taschenbuch | Deutsch | Tierfreier Nichtraucher-Haushalt | Schon der Anfang ist unglaublich: Stanley Yelnats geht nichts ahnend unter einer Brücke durch, als ihm die riesigen, übel riechenden Turnschuhe eines berühmten Baseballspielers auf den Kopf fallen. Und weil sein Vater an einem bahnbrechenden Recycling-Verfahren mit gebrauchten Turnschuhen arbeitet, hält Stanley die müffelnden Treter für ein Zeichen und nimmt sie mit. Pech, dass die Polizei schon nach dem Dieb sucht. Der Jugendrichter lässt Stanley die Wahl: Jugendgefängnis oder 18 Monate Camp Green Lake. Er entscheidet sich für das Camp. Die Hitze dort ist unerträglich, der Alltag hart, doch so schnell gibt Stanley nicht auf. | nan | BN0098 | Bücher: Kinderbücher / Jugendbücher: Jugendbuch allgemein>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer in dieser Sparte>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer von diesem Autor>> Alle Sparten dieses Verkäufers | 25.08.2022 | nan |
| 2 | Die Wanderhure – Buch gebraucht kaufen | should be scraped | Iny Lorentz | Die Wanderhure | 3426629348 (ISBN-13: 9783426629345) | leichte Gebrauchsspuren | Knaur Taschenbuch | 190x125x39 mm | 624 | 452 g | nan | nan | 2005 | Taschenbuch | Deutsch | Das Buch ist in einem guten Zustand und weist nur leichte Gebrauchsspuren auf. "Konstanz im Jahre 1410: Als Graf Ruppert um die Hand der schönen Bürgerstochter Marie anhält, kann ihr Vater der schönen Bürgerstochter Marie abhält, kann ihr Vater sein Glück kaum fassen. Er ahnt nicht, dass es dem adeligen Bewerber nur um das Vermögen seiner zukünftigen Frau geht und dass er dafür vor keinem Verbrechen zurückschreckt."Privatverkauf daher kein Rückgaberecht | Eine Frau kämpft in der grausamen Welt des Mittelalters um ihr Glück. Konstanz im Jahre 1410: Als Graf Ruppert um die Hand der schönen Bürgerstochter Marie anhält, kann ihr Vater sein Glück kaum fassen. Er ahnt nicht, dass es dem adligen Bewerber nur um das Vermögen seiner künftigen Frau geht und dass er dafür vor keinem Verbrechen zurückscheut. Marie und ihr Vater werden Opfer einer gemeinen Intrige, die das Mädchen zur Stadt hinaustreibt. Um zu überleben, muss sie ihren Körper verkaufen. Aber Marie gibt nicht auf ... Alle Bände der historischen Bestseller-Reihe rund um Marie Adler von Iny Lorentz in chronologischer Reihenfolge:• Die Wanderhure• Die Kastellanin• Das Vermächtnis der Wanderhure• Die List der Wanderhure• Die Wanderhure und die Nonne• Die Wanderhure und der orientalische Arzt• Die Tochter der Wanderhure• Töchter der Sünde• Die Wanderhure und der orientalische Arzt | Huren, Intrige, Konstanz, Marie Schärer, Marie Adler, Bürgerstochter, Ruppertus Splendidus, Grafensohn, Verdächtigung, Hübschlerin, Wanderschaft, Wanderhure, Konstanzer Konzil, Rache, Aufstand, Iny Lorentz Romane, historische Romane Mittelalter | BN00214 | Bücher: Romane / Erzählungen: Historische Romane>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer in dieser Sparte>> Mehr von diesem Verkäufer von diesem Autor>> Alle Sparten dieses Verkäufers | 21.08.2022 | nan |